# Understanding the output of the `who -a` command

Tags: sshd, utilities

I am asking this question because, while there are many answers on the internet showing that `who -a` is an option, nobody explains how to read the output.  If you could provide a link to an online site that explains this, that would be equally an awesome answer.   Here is an example of what I would like to decipher:

```
[bo@hostname ~]$ who -a
                        Jun 17 03:47               590 id=si    term=0 exit=0
           system boot  Jun 17 03:47
           run-level 3  Jun 17 03:47                   last=S
                        Jun 17 03:48              4424 id=l3    term=0 exit=0
LOGIN      tty1         Jun 17 03:48              5503 id=1
LOGIN      tty2         Jun 17 03:48              5504 id=2
LOGIN      tty3         Jun 17 03:48              5505 id=3
LOGIN      tty4         Jun 17 03:48              5506 id=4
LOGIN      tty5         Jun 17 03:48              5507 id=5
LOGIN      tty6         Jun 17 03:48              5508 id=6
           pts/0        Oct 19 16:27             15250 id=ts/0  term=0 exit=0
bo       + pts/1        Oct 23 12:24   .         19776 (10.10.10.93)
           pts/2        Oct 23 13:07              8551 id=ts/2  term=0 exit=0
           pts/3        Oct 22 10:36              5813 id=ts/3  term=0 exit=0
           pts/4        Oct 10 09:06             13002 id=ts/4  term=0 exit=0
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can find from `man who`

```
-a, --all
      same as -b -d --login -p -r -t -T -u
```

So let's look in details:

```
-b, --boot
      time of last system boot
```

this is string `system boot  Jun 17 03:47`

```
-d, --dead
      print dead processes
```

this is strings with `exit=0` at the end

```
-l, --login
      print system login processes
```

this is login ttys (strings with `LOGIN` in the beginning)

```
-p, --process
      print active processes spawned by init
```

this

```
-r, --runlevel
      print current runlevel
```

this is `run-level 3  Jun 17 03:47                   last=S`

next one is

```
-T, -w, --mesg
      add user's message status as +, - or ?
-u, --users
      list users logged in
```

this two string

```
bo       + pts/1        Oct 23 12:24   .         19776 (10.10.10.93)
```

Hope now it is more clear how to parse this output.

Comment: Thanks.  That is a good lesson on how to read a man page.  Thanks.

Comment: @djangofan and don't forget the more advanced info tool (`info who`) which sometimes goes in more details than man