# List all connected and previously connected users to SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I want to know who is accessing my server at any point in time and see logs from the past, however it is behind an SSH tunnel. How can I do this?

EDIT: See tags, running debian on both machines. SSHD is my SSH server.

EDIT: I already know how to [List all connected SSH sessions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/list-all-connected-ssh-sessions) but I don't know which if any apply to ssh tunnels. They all seem to refer to PTS or TTY and I don't think SSH tunnels are like that although I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the information you are looking for is available from the standard security logging/journaling service, which is included with `systemd` services.

Look into `/var/log/auth.log` in Debian installation or  `/var/log/secure` in Red-Hat installation , if its is not there you might wish to install and activate the journaling service.

Learn to dig into the journal with `journalctl` [command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html#).

Learn more about `journald` [service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journald.service.html).

Good luck with your dig.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `/var/log/secure` indeed does not exist however I shall do some research when I can.