# When all SSH sessions have been idle for more than a minute, shut down the machine

Tags: ssh, terminal

Idle is defined as when no foreground program is running and the terminal is waiting for user input, but the user does not make any input.

Actually, my ultimate goal is: shutdown when all `SSH` sessions are idle and `x-window` is also idle.
The idle time of `x-window` can be determined with `xprintidle`. So for now I just need to determine if all SSH sessions are idle or not.
I've looked for many ways to determine if a machine is idle in Linux, but most of them are based on `x-window` to determine if the desktop is idle.

Comment: There used to be a program called `timeoutd` which would log out users who had been idle for a configurable amount of time.  It used to be pretty popular to stop users from hogging scarce resources like modem dial-in lines.  I haven't seen it for many years and I don't think it's maintained any more.  Anyway if you could find that and recompile it for a modern distro (or find an alternative that does the same thing), you could shutdown when there are no ssh sessions logged in.

Answer (score -1):

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# default values
ClientAliveInterval                        0
ClientAliveCountMax                        3
```

If you set `ClientAliveInterval` to 600 {seconds} along with `ClientAliveCountMax` to 0 then that will close any SSH session that has been idle for 10 minutes.  By using this mechanism you could have any SSH session *cleanly* close after a specific timeout or idle period of your choosing.  Then check to see if there are any SSH sessions or processes present and if not then do a shutdown.

Recommend you also read up on those two SSH parameters before using them to be sure,

https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

[What do options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` in sshd_config do exactly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-d)

because someone doesn't believe me... edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to have `ClientAliveInterval 61` and `ClientAliveCountMax 0` and then have the below script run via crontab every minute and watch your machine shut down

```
#!/bin/bash

# ssh_idle_shutdown.bash
# the first num (a) in file /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt is 0 or 1 based on if a ssh connection has happened

# if a == 1 and count == 0 then do something

if [ ! -f /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt ]
then
    echo 0 > /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt
fi

count=`netstat -tnpa | grep 'ESTABLISHED.*sshd' | wc -l`

str=`head  /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt`
astr=${str:0:1}
a=$((astr))

if [ $a -eq 0 ] && [ $count -gt 0 ]
then
   echo 1 > /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt
elif [ $a -eq 1 ] && [ $count -eq 0 ]
then
   echo -n "ssh idle condition met system shutdown called at " >> /var/log/sshidleshutdownlog.txt
   date >> /var/log/sshidleshutdownlog.txt
   rm -f /var/run/sshidleshutdown.txt
#  execute /sbin/shutdown
fi
```

put this in `/etc/crontab`

```
1 * * * * *  root   /path_to/ssh_idle_shutdown.bash
```

and also do

```
chown root.root  /path_to/ssh_idle_shutdown.bash
chmod 700 /path_to/ssh_idle_shutdown.bash
```

this is letting the SSH server identify what idle sessions are, and then the ssh server is closing them.  Once we have seen at least one established ssh session then we begin checking until no ssh sessions are left via netstat, because the ssh server will have closed idle sessions based on `ClientAlive Interval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` in `sshd_config`.  Adjust `ClientAliveInterval` and `/etc/crontab` frequency for running this `ssh_idle_shutdown.bash` accordingly.

Comment: So wrong. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618) explains why.

Comment: let the US government know they are wrong too!  https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2021-06-14/finding/V-244525

Comment: *Within the sshd_config the product of the values of "ClientAliveInterval" and "ClientAliveCountMax" are used to establish the inactivity threshold*;

Comment: This forces the client to respond, the method only detects inactivity meaning "the client mysteriously disappeared from the network". The question is about when "the terminal is waiting for user input, but the user does not make any input". If only the network connection is fine, your method will make the server and the client exchange a "ping", so they will know the other side is still there. The client will respond even if it's "idle" by the definition of the OP.

Comment: no it does not force the client to respond.  if the client does not respond, if in putty under `connection` you have `seconds between keepalives` set to 0 the default then no keepalive *ping* will be sent, the ssh server will kill those sessions that have been idle for *ClientAliveInterva*l seconds.  Try it.  And like I said, not in so many words, write a script to run in the background that looks for no ssh connections [because idle ones will have been killed via *ClientAliveInterval* and then `if num_ssh_sessions == 0 /sbin/shutdown`.

Comment: And take into account the starting case of zero ssh sessions because nobody ssh'd in yet.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/list-all-connected-ssh-sessions

Comment: I think `seconds between keepalives` in PuTTY is like `ServerAliveInterval` in `ssh`. Keep-alive messages in SSH may be SSH_MSG_GLOBAL_REQUEST and per [RFC 4254](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4254#section-4) "both the client and server MAY send global requests at any time, and the receiver MUST respond appropriately". So if one end uses `*Alive*`, the other must respond. No response means the other end is AWOL. This is what the mechanism detects and formally disconnects. It does not detect situations where a user takes a break from typing on the client machine.

Comment: I can see your script. With what exact connection(s) (`ssh` command(s)) have you tested it? What do you do to keep them "idle"? What do you do to keep them "busy" (to make sure they get terminated only when idle)? How do you know the server part of each idle connection gets closed because of being idle? My test is simple: `ssh -vvv -N` …. This is extremely idle: after authentication and such, only keep-alive packets flow (until future rekeying, I guess). The server does not end the connection as "idle". The packets alone make the connection non-idle. It's been over 60x `ClientAliveInterval`.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about at this point.  I've explained enough.

Comment: i created an idle SSH connection. Your `ClientAlive*` settings not only fail in detecting its idleness, they keep it alive. I'm not surprised, these packets are exactly to keep connections alive. They are not a way to detect connections that are idle by the OP's definition.

Comment: you're doing something wrong.  Like I said, go tell the USG everything they're wrong too.

Comment: Ah, [*argumentum ab auctoritate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority). AFAIK RHEL used to have a misleading claim in its security guide. See [the bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1873547) and the discussion there. Is it possible the source you linked to has followed the buggy guide? I also note the handling of `ClientAliveCountMax=0` [chagned in OpenSSH](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2627). What is your SSH server and the version of it?

Comment: While digging, I discovered [`ChannelTimeout`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChannelTimeout) and [`UnusedConnectionTimeout`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#UnusedConnectionTimeout). They are [relatively new (OpenSSH 9.2, 2023-02-02)](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.2). **These are designed** to detect inactivity (as opposed to disappearance of the client detected by `ClientAlive*`) and they probably can be used to solve the question here. I learned something new, thank you. Are you going to investigate the new options and fix your answer? I will gladly vote up then.