# Find physical machine associated with /dev/pts/N

Tags: ssh, ip, devices

If i have an operating system with multiple users logged in via ssh, is there any way i can find which physical machine is associated with each /dev/pts/N (where N is an integer)?
All i know is the

> who

and

> ps -aux

commands that will show which user or process is associated with the device files, but can i get any more information about the physical machine that the user/process comes from? Maybe an I.P.?

Comment: A pseudo-terminal is not associated with a "physical machine". It's associated with a running process (e.g., ssh session, or a gui terminal window, a window in screen/tmux, etc). You can use `ps` to find what processes are using a given `pts` device, and potentially backtrack from there.

Comment: For what you're trying to do, the `ss` (or `netstat`) command might be more useful (e.g., `ss -tnp | grep sshd`)

Comment: Could you use one of the answers here?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/list-all-connected-ssh-sessions

Comment: @larsks at the end of the day i was getting confused because the process was spawned at the initialization of the machine (parent PID=1). So what you say makes perfect sense. I was looking for a ssh session or something similar, but there is none. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Glad to help. I've posted the comments as an answer (with a slightly longer example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pseudo-terminal is not associated with a "physical machine". It's associated with a running process (e.g., ssh session, or a gui terminal window, a window in screen/tmux, etc). You can use `ps` to find what processes are using a given `pts` device, and potentially backtrack from there.

For what you're trying to do, the `ss` (or `netstat`) command might be more useful. For example, I can find the remote addresses associated with active ssh connections by running something like:

```
$ ss -tnp | grep sshd | grep ESTAB
ESTAB      0      0      192.168.1.200:22                 1.2.3.4:39240               users:(("sshd",pid=2706,fd=3))
ESTAB      0      0      192.168.1.200:22                 4.3.2.1:39242               users:(("sshd",pid=2809,fd=3),("sshd",pid=2771,fd=3))
```

Comment: You helped me elucidate some wrong thoughts i was having: i was mistaking /dev/pts/N files with active ssh sessions. Indeed, although the process was associated with a pts/N, the pts was not associated with any active ssh session. ss helped me find the machine that the process was communicating with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SSH (and mosh) actually populate the `utmp`/`wtmp` files that e.g. `who` and `last` read with some useful information, including the remote IP address.

```
~$ who
...
ilkkachu  pts/26       2022-05-03 16:27 (127.0.0.1)
$ last -1a
ilkkachu  pts/26       Tue May  3 16:27   still logged in    127.0.0.1
```

Though you might want to grep for the correct tty name:

```
$ who | grep "pts/26"
ilkkachu  pts/26       2022-05-03 16:27 (127.0.0.1)
```

Alternatively, you could chase the list of open files to find the SSH process holding an fd on the tty, and then the corresponding network socket.

Comment: The command who indeed helped me. Particularly who -d showed that /pts/N was associated with a dead session. So in the end, although the process was communicating with a machine, it was not the machine that spawned it.